# How to split windows horizontally in emacs when executing current buffer?

Tags: emacs, split, elisp

I am coding in python using Emacs. I have modified ".emacs" to suit my needs. However, I do not know how to change the default vertical split behavior of windows when executing current buffer.

I know that:

```
(setq split-height-threshold nil) 
(setq split-width-threshold 0)
```

works in general. But it does not work when I execute buffer for the first time using `C-c C-c`

Despite having the above code in my ~/.emacs, the following happens on `C-c C-c` :
[image: vertical split :(]

I hope my question is clear, let me know if you have any idea about this.

Comment: Interestingly, when my emacs frame is wider than it is tall, Emacs by defualt opens windows side-by-side...

Comment: I am now doing `C-x 3` but I'm sure there must be a way to make it default in Emacs as Python-IDE

Comment: @lukstafi ... that's not what I am observing.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following. It fixes your problem (I hope) as well as preventing Emacs from splitting windows in the first place.

```
;;; ------------------------------------------------------------------
;;; display-buffer

;; The default behaviour of `display-buffer' is to always create a new
;; window. As I normally use a large display sporting a number of
;; side-by-side windows, this is a bit obnoxious.
;;
;; The code below will make Emacs reuse existing windows, with the
;; exception that if have a single window open in a large display, it
;; will be split horisontally.

(setq pop-up-windows nil)

(defun my-display-buffer-function (buf not-this-window)
  (if (and (not pop-up-frames)
           (one-window-p)
           (or not-this-window
               (not (eq (window-buffer (selected-window)) buf)))
           (> (frame-width) 162))
      (split-window-horizontally))
  ;; Note: Some modules sets `pop-up-windows' to t before calling
  ;; `display-buffer' -- Why, oh, why!
  (let ((display-buffer-function nil)
        (pop-up-windows nil))
    (display-buffer buf not-this-window)))

(setq display-buffer-function 'my-display-buffer-function)
```

Comment: I tried this, it didn't work. I think it might be because of some other setting I have turned on using some dot-el file.

Comment: Is your frame width lower than 162? Because that's the hardcoded value in the snippet above.

Comment: Irrespective of window size it doesn't split horizontally.